# Important Doctor Who (Original) Episodes to watch

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

I have already watched all previous seasons of Doctor Who (2005) and am waiting for the next season. I want to watch Doctor Who (60s) series, but it's not easy for me to watch 700 episodes in Black-and-white. I'd happily skip an episode if it's not important.

By important I mean, it must have a connection with currently running series (which can serve backstory or something). Or, it must be historically significant (popular or something).

What are the important episodes from the original series which can extend my knowledge of current series?

Comment: **Based on what's survived here are my suggestions**:
1st Doctor - 100,000 BC, The Keys Of Marinus, The Dalek Invasion Of Earth, The Rescue, The Romans, The Chase, The Time Meddler, The Tenth Planet. 
2nd Doctor - The Tomb Of The Cybermen, The Ice Warriors, The Seeds Of Death, The War Games [50th ep].
3rd Doctor - Inferno, The Claws Of Axos, Day Of The Daleks, The Three Doctors, Death To The Daleks.
4th Doctor - ALL [highlights- Genesis Of The Daleks, Revenge Of The Cybermen, The Deadly Assassin, The Face Of Evil, Horror Of Fang Rock, The Invasion Of Time, Destiny Of The Daleks, City Of Death]

Comment: **Suggestions con't**:
5th Doctor (of which I was not a fan) - Earthshock, The Five Doctors, Resurrection Of The Daleks.
6th Doctor - Attack Of The Cybermen, The Mark Of The Rani, The Two Doctors [this ep kind of makes no sense but whatever it's got Patrick Troughton arguably the BEST Doctor there was], Revelation Of The Daleks, The Trial Of A Time Lord (which is 14 episodes long and rather a different type of story).
7th Doctor - Time And The Rani, Remembrance Of The Daleks, Battlefield, The Curse Of Fenric, Dimensions In Time.
8th Doctor - Doctor Who TV Movie produced for the US in 1996.

Comment: I did miss one in my "*highlights*" for The 4th Doctor, really very silly too because it's one of the best of the entire series: **The Talons Of Weng-Chiang**.  Though I would still say watch ALL of his.  On average they're entertaining but when they're good, they're GREAT!  Tom Baker is my second favorite Doctor and probably the most popular before the 2005 reboot. Plus none of his episodes are _lost_.

Comment: @22nd I loved Tom's doctor, but the horns of nimon is painful. The leisure hive, creature from the pit and meglos are masterpieces in comparison but still.

Comment: I answered a very similar question over at movies & tv se some time ago.  The answer is incomplete (I hadn't finished them myself when I wrote it), but you can see it here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19727/how-far-back-do-i-need-to-watch-doctor-who-for-it-to-still-make-sense/19855#19855

Answer (score 4):

Arguably, every old episode has a connection to the current series, even if only to demonstrate how much has changed over the years.

I won't try to find links, but Wikipedia is a good place to start http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_who.

Suggestions -

- The very first episode from 1963
- Each companion
- Each regeneration and each actor to have played The Doctor
- The debuts of notable adversaries e.g. The Daleks, The Cybermen, The Master etc.
- Episodes written by notable writers e.g. Douglas Adams
- While you are following these threads, if you happen across a writer whose work you like, other episodes by them
- Similarly, if you have a favourite adversary, you could seek out more of their appearances

Comment: +1 Because I thought this was a good logical answer and it deserved more respect than the rather subjective commends.